# Share tableviewcontroller with two tabviewcontrollers

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have 2 `UITableViewcontroller` embedded in a `UITableViewcontroller` A and B which opens on a button click. Now i want the same 2 `UITableViewcontroller` to be opened on click of an other button but in reverse order B and A.

I tried creating a new `UITableViewcontroller` and embedding in the storyboard but did not work. Can anyone please suggest how to accomplish the same and oblige.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Share code and elaborate question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using to "present modally" views for the 2 tableviews. The 2 tableViews will be opened in a Window , the you can just switch the views with every button press